# Case Issue in SQL statement with IN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I ve following simple case statement

```
 CASE WHEN @SPOID is not null THEN 
            (176)
       ELSE
            (SELECT designationID from setupdesignations where reportto = 99)
       END
```

When else clause of this statement execute it gives me the following error

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I am using this statement in the `IN` clause I was expecting multiple result to be returned in else case but it is giving me the above error. If I remove the case statement and execute the else part in query then i get the expected result

Comment: this is just a value. whatever returned from here should go in the IN block in query above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use a subselect as an expression within a CASE match, it expects a single value. Instead how about;

```
where 
  (@SPOID is not null and infield = 176)
or
  (@SPOID is null and infield in (SELECT designationID from setupdesignations where reportto = 99))
```

Answer (score 2):

Although you are using `IN` clause, the `CASE` statement only allows one row as return statement.

You'll have to figure another way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a dynamic query to achieve you end goal.  The following link might point you in the right direction - check the last post: http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=150247

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your in clause to:

```
... in 
(SELECT designationID 
 from setupdesignations 
 where reportto = 99 and @SPOID is not null
 UNION
 SELECT 176 where @SPOID is null)
```